# Why are we more averse to negativity?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

There is a tendency for humans to be more sensitive to negative emotion rather than positive — something very positive will generally have less of an impact on a person's behaviour and cognition than something equally emotional but negative. For example, losing 5 dollars is more emotionally taxing than gaining 5 dollars is emotionally stimulating. This is known as [negative bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negativity_bias).

I am trying to understand why we have evolved with such a trait — could it attributed to our evolutionary success as a species, or rather because, since there is more unknown than known (our perceptions reveal to us a fraction of the world), that the natural default position to be is more negatively-titled?

Comment: Opportunities for gain will usually have another chance if one is missed. But a single wrong move can mean game over.

Comment: @Michael the problem comes when you meet the opportunity to avoid a wrong move